# solve_ivp - TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm working on the code below for a class and no matter what I try I can't figure out how to fix it so I can move on.

```
def eqs(t, x):
    return np.array([[(1 - np.multiply((1 - f(z(t), z_thresh)), (1 - f(x(1), y_thresh)))) - x(0)],
                                [(1 - np.multiply((1 - f(z(t), z_thresh)),(1 - f(x(0), x_thresh)))) - x(1)]])


f = lambda x, thresh: x >= thresh
z = lambda t: np.multiply((t >= 2), (t <= 4))

z_thresh = 0.5
y_thresh = 0.5
x_thresh = 0.5

x_0 = np.zeros([0,])

sol = int.solve_ivp(eqs, range(0, 6), x_0)
```

I've been banging my head against the wall all night and can't figure out how to get around. No matter what I seem to try it still throws "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable."

Edit: The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7252/1552450284.py in <module>
      9 x0 = np.zeros([0,])
     10 
---> 11 sol = int.solve_ivp(eqns_a,range(0,6),x0)
     12 plt.figure(1)
     13 subplot(311)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\ivp.py in solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method, t_eval, dense_output, events, vectorized, args, **options)
    540         method = METHODS[method]
    541 
--> 542     solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
    543 
    544     if t_eval is None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\rk.py in __init__(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, max_step, rtol, atol, vectorized, first_step, **extraneous)
     92         self.max_step = validate_max_step(max_step)
     93         self.rtol, self.atol = validate_tol(rtol, atol, self.n)
---> 94         self.f = self.fun(self.t, self.y)
     95         if first_step is None:
     96             self.h_abs = select_initial_step(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py in fun(t, y)
    136         def fun(t, y):
    137             self.nfev += 1
--> 138             return self.fun_single(t, y)
    139 
    140         self.fun = fun

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py in fun_wrapped(t, y)
     18 
     19     def fun_wrapped(t, y):
---> 20         return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)
     21 
     22     return fun_wrapped, y0

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7252/1552450284.py in <lambda>(t, x)
      6 x_thresh = 0.5
      7 
----> 8 eqns_a = lambda t, x: np.array([[(1 - np.multiply((1 - f(z(t), z_thresh)), (1 - f(x(1), y_thresh)))) - x(0)], [(1 - np.multiply((1 - f(z(t), z_thresh)),(1 - f(x(0), x_thresh)))) - x(1)]])
      9 x0 = np.zeros([0,])
     10 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please post the full error and a [mcve]. That will also contain clues to help you find the cause of the problem.

Comment: You don't want to work your way around the problem, you need to first identify the problem.  Which variable is an array, when it really should be function.  Debugging is not  a game of darts where through a whole lot of things at the problem in hopes of hitting the target!

Comment: Did you look at the error traceback?  Try to identify where the problem occurs?  You sure didn't think it important enough to show it to us!.

Comment: My apologies, I'm totally fried. I have added the traceback to the original post.

Comment: In the functions `eqs`, `x` is an array, not a function.  Use `x[0]` and `x[1]` to index the array, not `x(0)` and `x(1)`.

Comment: Yeah! That took care of it, thank you! Now to work on the rest of the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the traceback tells you that the problem is in

```
np.array([[(1 - np.multiply((1 - f(z(t), z_thresh)), (1 - f(x(1), y_thresh)))) - x(0)], [(1 - np.multiply((1 - f(z(t), z_thresh)),(1 - f(x(0), x_thresh)))) - x(1)]]
```

So we look for apparent function calls, `fn(...)`.  `np.multiply` should be ok unless you redefined it somplace.  `f(...)` is defined with a `lambda`.  `z(...)` as well.  That leaves `x(1)` and `x(0)`.  What is `x`?  It's the lambda function argument.